# Some Users (8 out of 83) cannot access my script.google web app

Tags: google-apps-script

After launching google script Web App 8 out of 83 users cannot access my Web app, Error like "This site can't be reached", "Web Page Not Available" prompt on the browser.

I already tried Deploying another version but problem persists.

The Settings are, can be access by anyone(even anonymous)

PS. We tried accessing the Web app on Vpn and it works, but when the VPN is off, the problem comes back.

Thank you for everyone whose going to share their solution.

Comment: Are they using old browsers (IE 9)? Do you have an error message on your project log?

Comment: They are using chrome, and they even use their own phone to try, but they still cant access the web app. Is there a limit on who can access Google app script web app?

Comment: Since your app is published as "anyone(even anonymous)" your only limit should be to keep the simultaneous executions below 30 users for doGet()/dopost() calls and below 10 for run() calls. But that doesn't seem to be the problem here, so I do not know... sorry.

Comment: by the way, those user who cannot access the web app, cannot even access the script.google.com website

Comment: It sounds more like a network restriction. Check if your Router/Proxy is restricting google content.

Comment: I wonder if any of the 8 users are logged into other google accounts.  There have been issues with users logged into multiple google accounts that has cause authentication errors. So you might take a look at that.  I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Okay, Thank you I will check that. And also on execution logs, it says on the status that it is Complete although the user cannot see the web app